# How to fix "laravel mail send not work on live server working on localhost"?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, centos7, sendmail, laravel-5.8

I have a laravel 5.8 on the AWS lightsail instance then when sending email it works perfectly on localhost but not on live server. I have also two laravel 5.2 application that can send email on each instance server in AWS lightsail and it works well. Then my problem is when i try to used laravel 5.8 it doesnt send email using smtp. I'm running php 7.1 on centos 7 with nginx. I don't get an error too.

I tried to telnet smtp.muumuu-mail.com with 25,587,465 , the respond is okay.
that is also the smtp that i used both laravel 5.2 application and it works okay.

I tried also putting my configuration on config/mail.php but it doesn't work too.

This is my .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.muumuu-mail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=support@mymail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

This is the code i used for sending email

```
 Mail::send('main\mail',['data' => $data], function($msg) use($data) {

            $msg->to('bolo@getnada.com');
            $msg->subject('this is a sample');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

this is for sending on gmail. this will help you.
.env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Here is email store controller

```
public function store(SendEmailRequest $request)

{
    $data = [
        'email'=>$request->email,
        'subject'=>$request->subject,
        'message'=>$request->message
    ];
    // sending email
    Mail::to('infodemands747@gmail.com')->send(new ContactMail($data));
    session()->flash('success' , 'Thanks For Contacting! We Will Right Back Soon');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: I don't use gmail. . I use different smtp server then gmail works on my localhost too but not on server

Comment: your server name??

Comment: i just use AWS lightsail instance for live server hosting. And my smtp is smtp.muumuu-mail.com

Comment: I have faced the same problem. have you got the solution?